# « Ne prends pas de passagers » : emploi fautif ?

Tags: grammaire, usage

Οn some buses' line display I have seen the notice

> Ne prends pas de passagers.

I think that this is faulty, isn't it ? Shouldn't it be

> Je ne prends pas de passagers.

or even

> Ne pas prendre de passagers.

?

According to me, the only reason that justifies the usage of the first sentence is the space constraint; but still it sounds awkward.

Comment: "The sign of a bus" is not defined; what you read on a sign is not really called a message; a board or sign with information on it is "a notice"; ithink that that is faulty, isn't it?;

Comment: @LPH. Thanks. I corrected it. I hope it is OK now.

Comment: "the board of a bus": not defined; what is it exactly, simply letters on the body of the bus, that is outside, directly over the paint? Not "doesn't it ?" but "isn't it,". Also, avoid twice the word "notice": I've seen.

Comment: @LPH https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjYzMugxeXfAhVRaFAKHVvTBywQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lesequestre.fr%2Fmes-infos-pratiques%2Ftransports%2Fbus%2F&psig=AOvVaw0FIQxmvacctZzNXH4zshHn&ust=1547289117164973

Comment: @LPH Par contre les autobus que j'ai vus ont la notice "Ne prends pas de passagers". Mais je ne suis pas sûr pour le "s". Il me faut voir avec plus d'attention.

Comment: I can see clearly what you mean now; you could call that "the line display" (l'affichage de ligne) and get by with it. PS I verified on this picture you provide, although it is not needed (it would be silly), there is no s.

Comment: @LPH Thanks. I am wondering about the "s". One of reasons that this notice attract my interest was that "Ne prends pas de passagers" contains the s that looks and sounds awkward. Nevertheless, I have to verify the very presence of it:-)!

Comment: I still don't get it! I can't figure out what you're trying to say!

Comment: @LPH : Sorry for not being clear. The notice I referred to, says, "Ne prend**s** pas de passagers". But I am not sure now for the bold s (prends instead of prend). jlliagre and you have already addressed this issue in your answers. So I have to check it again:-)!

Comment: Then, you are trying to say that you are very sure there was an s and that it had seemed strange to you, but yet you'll look at it one last time.

Comment: @LPH Yes, but in any case I still learn new things today:-)!

Comment: @LPH Finalement c'est sans s! Je l'ai vu clairement. Vous avez raison jlliagre et vous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forme:

> Ne **prend** pas de passagers.

est correcte. Elle indique simplement dans l'espace disponible à l'affichage, que ***ce bus*** ne prend pas de passagers (*ce bus* étant sous-entendu).

Ce n'est pas vraiment le conducteur qui s'exprime mais la compagnie de transport, donc le deuxième choix est à éviter, ce n'est pas non plus une instruction destinée au conducteur, donc le troisième choix n'est pas le bon.

Answer (score 3):

Les trois formes considérées sont incorrectes ; la première le devient après un petite modification orthographique ; il s'agit seulement d'enlever le s ;

- Ne prend pas de passagers

Avec le s on aurait un impératif, lequel dirait aux lecteurs de ne pas prendre de passagers, et cela n'a aucun sens.

« Ne prend pas de passager » est une forme elliptique de « Cet autobus ne prend pas de passagers ».

En style télégraphique, on aurait précisément « **bus prend pas passager** » ; le style télégraphique consiste à éliminer un maximum de mots dans une phrase tout en conservant le sens. Le style elliptique dépend du contexte (affichage sur un autobus, il est question de prendre des passagers), pas le style télégraphique.